# If MIPS architecture had 64 registers instead of 34 registers

Tags: architecture, cpu, instructions

I was asked a question that if the number of registers doubled, how this would affect the size of the registers. I came to the conclusion that they would have instead size `log(64) = 6`. But how would the size of the R-type and I-type instructions change from this?

Comment: Explain to how R-type and I-type instructions are structured or [laid out](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html) bit-wise. At the end, you should be able to tell me :)

Comment: R type instruction is:

Bit[31-26] op, Bit[25-21] rs, Bit[20-16] rt, Bit[15-11], rd Bit[10-6], shamt Bit[5-0] function. Oh I guess it would increase to size 35 bits?

Comment: And the size of the offset would remain the same for I-type, so 34 bits?

Comment: Currently each register takes 5 bits to encode (2^5=32). To name 64 registers (2^6=64) it would take 6 bits to encode. However, if the number of bits per-opcode devoted to the registers increases, the size of the 'other parts' has to decrease. Eg: 3 more register bits for R-type means 3 less bits for shamt/funct! -- what happens!?! If the opcode size is increased to 35/34-bits then it no longer fits along memory boundaries and a second 32-bit "word" has to be used for the remaining 3/2-bits -- ouch!

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to know which gets decreased by what? Is it 2 less for shamt, 1 less for funct? I'm not sure how to decrease by how much for those two. And I guess similarly for I-type, the offset and opcode would have to decrease by 3 too

Comment: But would those still be 'useful' if decreased? What is 'given up' to get more registers within the current opcode structure? There is indeed very severe trade-offs when trying to add additional registers to the MIPS layout. (Note that I-Type only has 2 named registers vs 3 for R-Type instructions.)

Comment: I don't think so, because you wouldn't know which operand to even use if it was decreased. But if you can't increase or decrease the others, what do you do?

Comment: I believe they are just invalid then

Comment: Say "MIPS was designed for 32 registers, and attempting to add additional registers imposes severe compatibility (as in, it's NOT MIPS) and/or other limitations"? :) Justify such statements using the arguments/information above.

Comment: My argument would be that the R-instruction is invalid because the funct would have to be reduced. And same for the I-instruction, as the offset would have to be reduced.

Comment: So - I guess, the 'answer' depends on what the person asking the question is expecting and the specific details/restrictions therein.